# Criteria for $f(f(x))=g(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

I 'm searching about the **solvability of the functional equation $f(f(x))=g(x)$**. I have three questions about it:

1. Let's be $g$ an arbitrary function and the functional equation $f(f(x))=g(x)$. Are there any specific criteria to ensure us that there exist such function $f$?
2. Let's be $g\in C^0$ and the functional equation $f(f(x))=g(x)$. Are there any specific criteria to ensure us that there exist such function $f$ and $f\in C^0$?
3. Let's be $g\in C^1$ and the functional equation $f(f(x))=g(x)$. Are there any specific criteria to ensure us that there exist such function $f$ and $f\in C^1$?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.:** I read [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffx-gx) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66538/finding-f-such-that-ffx-gx-given-g), but there are a little bit different questions.

Comment: The question may be too broad. Do you have any specific examples in mind?

Comment: The answer in 1 would be Ulm invariants.  See my answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/17869/454

Comment: @Bullet51 , I hope that there will be something like the discriminant on the quadratic equations.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar , thanks for your answer!!!